# Why does this class compile even though it does not properly implement its interface?

Tags: java, generics

a List then Why does the code (below) compile?  Surely `MyClass2` should return a `List<Integer>` ?

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(final String[] args) {
    MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
    List list = myClass.getList();
    System.out.println(list);
    System.out.println(list.get(0).getClass());

    MyClass2 myClass2 = new MyClass2();
    List list2 = myClass2.getList();
    System.out.println(list2);
    System.out.println(list2.get(0).getClass());
  }

  public interface Int1 {
    public List getList();
  }

  public interface Int2 extends Int1 {
    @Override
    public List<Integer> getList();
  }

  public static class MyClass implements Int2 {
    @Override
    public List<Integer> getList() {
      return Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
    }
  }

  public static class MyClass2 implements Int2 {
    @Override
    public List getList() {
      return Arrays.asList("One", "Two", "Three");
    }
  }
}
```

I have noticed if you try to make it a `List<String>` then you get an error "java: Main.MyClass2 is not abstract and does not override abstract method getList() in Main.Int2".  I don't quite understand why you don't get this in the example above.

Note: The solution to the problem in my project is to make the interface itself generic, i.e. `Int1<X>` (of course I use better names than this, its just an example).

Comment: You should normally have warnings in your compiler output

Comment: Because Java Generics suck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is in [JLS 7 5.5.1. Reference Type Casting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5.1):

> Given a compile-time reference type S (source) and a compile-time
>   reference type T (target), a casting conversion exists from S to T if
>   no compile-time errors occur due to the following rules.
>
> If S is a class type:
>
> ```
> If T is a class type, then either |S| <: |T|, or |T| <: |S|. Otherwise, a compile-time error occurs.
>
> Furthermore, if there exists a supertype X of T, and a supertype Y of S, such that both X and Y are provably distinct parameterized types
> ```
>
> (§4.5), and that the erasures of X and Y are the same, a compile-time
>   error occurs.

In your case `List<Integer>` and `List<String>` are provably distinct  parameterized types and they both have same erasures: `List`.

Answer (score 7):

I suspect, the compiler should be giving you warning for *Unchecked conversion*, rather than marking it as compiler error. Let's understand why does it warn you:

You have following two methods to implement to satisfy the contract of interface you implement:

```
public List getList();
public List<Integer> getList();
```

Now, if in your class, you just provide implementation of the first method, it can handle the request for the 2<sup>nd</sup> method. You can return a `List<Integer>` with the return type being `List`. That's because a `List<Integer>` is nothing but a `List` at runtime, due to *type erasure*.

But, if you just give the 2<sup>nd</sup> method implementation, it won't satisfy the contract of first method. First method says, it can return any type of `List`, since it has used raw type in the return type. So, it can return `List<Integer>`, `List<Object>`, `List<String>`, anything. But the 2<sup>nd</sup> method can only return `List<Integer>`.

Compiler will do this type checking at compile time and it will give you warning, that `List` requires unchecked conversion to `List<Integer>`, because the conversion will anyhow succeed at runtime, due to type erasure.

---

This is the similar case as below:

```
List<String> listString = new ArrayList<String>();
List rawList = new ArrayList();

listString = rawList;  // Warning: Unchecked conversion
rawList = listString;
```

---

**Suggested Reading**:

- [Can I cast to a parameterized type?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#Can%20I%20cast%20to%20a%20parameterized%20type?)

Comment: I don't get how we have "two interfaces contract to satisfy".  One interface overrides the other, so surely it is `Int2` which `MyClass2` has to satsify?  How can a request for a `List` handle one for a `List<Integer>` ? I know that they are the same after type erasure but they are not the same before its compiled because in the latter it checks the types of what you add to it/remove from it etc.

Comment: @PaulRichards. Yeah actually, technically you are implementing a single interface only. Which extends the first interface. So, you can say that you have to satisfy the contract of the single interface only. That inherits method from a different interface.

Comment: As I said, a method with return type `List` can return any list type. So, it can also return `List<Integer>`. So, that is what the other method is all about. It should return `List<Integer>`, which is taken care by `List`.

Comment: Yeah they are not the same at compile time. That is why compiler gives you unchecked conversion warning. Because it isn't sure both the list are same or not.

Answer (score 4):

The signature of `public List<Integer> getList()` is the same as the signature of `public List getList()` after type erasure. For overriding methods you need the overriding method to be a subsignature of the overridden method. The compiler here will decide that the subclass method does override the interface one if they are identical after type erasure and we can never have a conflict.

Answer (score 4):

This, literally, has no effect because of type erasure:

```
public interface Int1 {
     public List getList();
}

public interface Int2 extends Int1 {
     @Override
     public List<Integer> getList();
}
```

At runtime, any `List<X>` becomes `List`. Therefore you don't `@Override` anything here. The runtime prototype of `.getList()` is `List getList()`. The fact that you parameterize your `List` in `Int2` is completely ignored.

The compiler warns you about this:

```
java: Note: Main.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
java: Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

Answer (score 2):

Int2 extends Int1 then List is ok,

```
List<String>
```

does not compile because it is not defined in Int1 or in Int2.

```
List<Integer>
```

in

```
Int2
```

is subject to type erasure according to Java spec http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like its related to type erasure and its the sort of thing that generates a warning rather than a compiler error.  I guess it is like the other unchecked conversion scenarios I've seen before.  Thanks for the well researched answers people.